Power Automate task runs manually, won't run as a scheduled task
I am currently working on a task using Power Automate, where I need to create a flow that automatically exports specific details from my Outlook calendar to a SharePoint list every morning at 8:45 AM (UTC+2). The exported data includes the following calendar event details:
Meeting Title
Start and End Time
Participants' Emails
Link to the Meeting
While I have successfully built the flow and confirmed it works correctly during manual testing, I am experiencing an issue where the automation does not run automatically at the scheduled time. The data only transfers when I test the flow manually.
I suspect there might be a problem with the recurrence trigger or another configuration setting in the flow.
For your reference, I have attached a screenshot of the flow’s actions to provide additional context.

I would really appreciate your suggestions on how to resolve this issue so the data is automatically exported to the SharePoint list as scheduled.

Perhaps share what how your Recurrence trigger is configured.

Interval and frequency:

every day
Time zone:
UTC+2
Start time
Example: 2017-03-24T15:00:00Z
At these hours
8
At these minutes
45
Preview
Runs at 8:45 every day


Can you show a screenshot of the recurrence trigger configuration, it's not that we don't trust you but we don't trust you.  :-)

In the Power Automate's run history, check to see if the process was skipped. If there are errors, check error logs, which may show why the trigger condition was not met or why the run failed.
